Cómo ocultar la pantalla actual cuando la aplicación pasa a segundo plano en React Native Android
Estoy teniendo un problema en android con ocultar el contenido o mostrar un splash al estar la aplicación en segundo plano.
Estaba usando  AppState , y se muestra correctamente en los android que tienen navegación mediante gestos, pero no funciona correctamente al usar la navegación por medio de tres teclas, no comprendo el porqué se presenta este comportamiento.
Opté por probar algo nativo y me encontré el  FLAG_SECURE  y funciona bien con ambos tipos de navegación. El problema que tengo con esto es que no me permite tomar capturas de pantalla.
Hay alguna forma de poder ocultar el contenido al estar el app en segundo plano y te permita seguir tomando capturas de pantalla?
